# How to write bold text in a word document using excel-vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Writing data in a excel doc to a word doc.
But I can't figure out how to make all the parts named text in bold any help would be appreciated.

```
    L_CurrentHeading = "Text1: " & Cells(Q.Row, ACol) & " " & Cells(Q.Row, JCol) & "   |   Text 3: " & Cells(Q.Row, BCol)
    L_ID = "Text 2: " & Cells(Q.Row, CCol) & "   |   Text6: " & Cells(Q.Row, DCol) & "   |   " & Cells(Q.Row, ECol) & " Inspection " & Cells(Q.Row, FCol)
    L_Reading = "Text7: " & Cells(Q.Row, GCol) & " " & Cells(Q.Row, HCol)
    L_Note = "Text: " & Cells(Q.Row, ICol)
    L_ID = L_ID & vbCrLf & L_CurrentHeading & vbCrLf & L_Reading & vbCrLf & L_Note
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - everything else looks good.

Comment: @Jurik Thank you, I will try and do better.

Comment: Do you know that you can search for "Text1:" and replace it with the same text with's it's font property set to bold. To understand it better, press CTRL H in Word and then check in `Format` under `Replace` in the dialog box.

Comment: Record a macro for the above. Give it a try and if you are stuck then post the code that you tried and then we will take it from there. I just tested the code and it works :)